# Regular Expression constructor with variable not working, but seems correct

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to match a whole word. In a case where I have India and Indianapolis, both are matched, and if I try any grouping, then both are NOT matched, so I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Everything seem right.

So here is the select list which triggers the function right after it.

```
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="USA">United States</option>

$(".filter").on("change",function(){
  var $filter = $(this);
  var $selected = $filter.val(); //get selected filter box value
  var $table = $("#courses-table"); //get table 
  //$table.find("tr").show(); 
  var $filterType = $filter.data("filter");//get what to filter

  var $tablecell = $table.find("."+$filterType); //now look for rows that match the selected value and show them.
  var $match = new RegExp( $selected );

  $.each( $tablecell, function(){

    if( !$match.test( $(this).text() ) ) 
    {

      $(this).closest("tr").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Where $selected is a variable from a select menu. This cycles through a series of table cells and looking for the word India in two strings like this

```
Indianapolis, AMER, USA
```

and one like this

```
Hyderabad, APAC, India
```

Yet it is matching both. So I get that I need grouping, but when I try this

```
var $match = new RegExp( "(" + $selected + ")" );
```

It doesn't work. I tried word boundary \b and beginning and end of input ^ and $ but those don't work either. I'm outputting to console and word boundary is giving me some weird character. Obviously beginning and end of input worn't work because India is at the end, and this filter is meant to look for the word ANYWHERE it may exist in the string. What am I missing?

EDIT: I am using the same JS function for country, city and region so it could be looking for any of those items, BUT IN THIS CASE Let's say that the word I'm looking for is India in the two strings I posted above. The problem now is that it is matching in both strings, but it needs to match in ONLY ONE where India is the country? Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem.

Comment: in this case it's India, I'll post the rest of the code

Comment: What do you actually want to match? Just cities or both cities and regions and countries?

Comment: cities, regions and countries. It's working fine except that it is not matching whole words

Comment: FYI: you need to remove `g` from the regex declaration if you are using the regex with `.test()`. `var $match = new RegExp( $selected);`

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew I tried it both ways, but I'll take it out for the final

Comment: What is the regular expression ? Care to show it ?

Comment: It ends up being /India/ or /^India$/ or /(India)/ none of which work.

Comment: If you set up a fiddle, codepen or something like this it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Did you try `var $match = new RegExp( "\\b" + $selected + "\\b" );`?

Comment: You the man @Nick ! that did the trick!